# problems with including mysql.h in a C program (vs code)

Tags: mysql, c

i'm trying to include the **mysql.h library** in C, i installed the C connector.zip in the same folder but it doesn't seem to work, the documentation is cryptic and i can't figure out what i should do.

I got the C++ connector.zip from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/), it shoud be the official website of mysql (the connector should work also in C).

[This is the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9y9O.png)

My compiler is the C/C++ estenction in vs code and all the vs code settings are the default ones

my code looks like this for now (i'm just trying to include it)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main()
{
    //do stuff
    return 0;
}
```

this is the errors i get:

> #include errors have been detected. Update includePath. Revision marks are disabled for this conversion unit
>
> cannot open source file "mysql.h" error code
>
> mysql.h: No such file or directory

any advice? or some readable documentation?

Comment: "but it doesn't seem to work" Why do you know that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. First of all, `mysql.h` is not a libary. It is only a header telling the compiler what it might find in other source files or libraries. Second, where did you get that .zip file and how does your folder structure look after "installing" it? Third: How do you build your program? What compiler do you use? How did you configure VS Code? Fourth: What is the error message you get? Please copy exact and complete message as formatted text into the question.

Comment: Fifth: If you placed the header into local folder instead of system include path, you either need to add the include folder to compiler option or you might try to use `"headerfile.h"` instead of `<headerfile.h>`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would suggest sharing more details in your question, especially about your compilation workflow (compiler name and version, OS etc)

VS Code not recognizing an include is not necessarily indicating that the library is not installed. You could verify this by trying to compile your C program and see whether or not the include raises an issue.

If your program doesn't compile, then it is either that the library is not installed correctly or that the compiler doesn't know how to reach the library (you have to update the include paths on your system)

Lastly, some libraries require linking pre-compiled object/shared files, which would require you to configure the linker to make sure these library files get linked (in `gcc` that would be with the `-l` flag e.g. `-lmath`)